# User create and update using updateOrCreate()

Tags: laravel

I am creating and updating user using below code.

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $request->validate([
                'name'      => 'required',
                'email'     => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' .$request->user_id,
                'password'  => 'required',
                'role'      => 'required',
            ]);

            $user = User::updateOrCreate(['id' => $request->user_id],
            [
                'name'      => $request->name,
                'email'     => $request->email,
                'role'      => $request->role,
                'password'  => Hash::make($request->password)
            ]);
        }
    }
```

When I am updating record `Password` is updating also.  How can I solve the issue ?

How validation is working here `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' .$request->user_id,` when I am creating a record ? Because when I am creating a record at that time `$request->user_id` is not available.

Comment: Don't use `updateOrCreate`. You should have separate methods for store and update.

Comment: Thanks @miken32. Why shouldn't I use `updateOrCreate` ? What should I use ? Thanks.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, I would suggest using `create()` to create models, and `update()` to update them.

Comment: Thanks @miken32. Could you please say about validation  `'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' .$request->user_id` ? Thanks.

Comment: This rule: `unique:table,column,except,idColumn` ignores `$request->user_id` when creating a user (as this is unknown in this situation) and allows a user with id of `$request->user_id` to be excluded from verification when updating. Last parameter is optional, in case your id columns has a name other than `id`.